# Reassigning the 'command' part of a range of tkinter buttons created using a class

Tags: python-3.x, class, tkinter

Halfway through my program i want to change a range of button instances' "when clicked" commands. The buttons were created using the following class:

```
class GameBoardButtons:

def __init__(self, name, buttonText, buttonRow, buttonColumn, buttonState, frame, colour):
    self.name = name
    self.button = Button(frame, text=buttonText, fg=colour,
                         height=2, width=5, state=buttonState,
                         command=lambda: shipListAppendFunc(self))
    self.button.grid(row=buttonRow, column=buttonColumn)

def GridPosAttackable(self):
    self.button.config(command=lambda: whenAttacked(self.name))
```

And the function that i am calling to adjust the buttons is as follows:

```
def reconfigureButtons(grid):

    children = grid.children
    for c in children:
        widget = children[c]
        if isinstance(widget, (Button)):
            widget.configure(command=lambda: whenAttacked(c.name))
```

Should i be instead calling the function within the class ("GridPosAttackable")? And if so, how would i do that? The current way i have it, all the buttons call the same "self.name", not their unique name.

I want to make it so when "whenAttacked(whatever)" is called, the field/'whatever' part it takes is the buttons unique ID/'self' label.

Many thanks to all forms of help!

Comment: What is the `grid` argument in `reconfigureButtons(grid)`.

Comment: Maybe you can replace `self.name` by `self.button.winfo_name()` when calling `whenAttacked(...)` in `GridPosAttackable(...)`.